# Error upgrading mariadb-10.1 to 10.2 on debian 9

Tags: debian, mariadb, plesk

What about this error? upgrading on debian 9 with plesk from mariadb 10.1 to 10.2

Any clue how to fix it and continue upgrade?

```
apt install mariadb-server-10.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libmariadb3 libmariadbclient18 mariadb-client-10.2 mariadb-client-core-10.2 mariadb-server-core-10.2
Suggested packages:
  mariadb-test netcat-openbsd tinyca
Recommended packages:
  libhtml-template-perl
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  default-mysql-server mariadb-client-10.1 mariadb-client-core-10.1 mariadb-server-10.1 mariadb-server-core-10.1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libmariadb3 mariadb-client-10.2 mariadb-client-core-10.2 mariadb-server-10.2 mariadb-server-core-10.2
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libmariadbclient18
1 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 5 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/11.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 46.1 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 97530 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing default-mysql-server (1.0.2) ...
dpkg: mariadb-server-10.1: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 plesk-mysql-server depends on virtual-mysql-server | mysql-server; however:
  Package virtual-mysql-server is not installed.
  Package mariadb-server-10.1 which provides virtual-mysql-server is to be removed.
  Package mysql-server is not installed.
 plesk-mysql-server depends on virtual-mysql-server | mysql-server; however:
  Package virtual-mysql-server is not installed.
  Package mariadb-server-10.1 which provides virtual-mysql-server is to be removed.
  Package mysql-server is not installed.
 plesk-mysql-server depends on virtual-mysql-server | mysql-server; however:
  Package virtual-mysql-server is not installed.
  Package mariadb-server-10.1 which provides virtual-mysql-server is to be removed.
  Package mysql-server is not installed.
 plesk-mysql-server depends on virtual-mysql-server | mysql-server; however:
  Package virtual-mysql-server is not installed.
  Package mariadb-server-10.1 which provides virtual-mysql-server is to be removed.
  Package mysql-server is not installed.

Removing mariadb-server-10.1 (10.1.47-0+deb9u1) ...
(Reading database ... 97403 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mariadb-server-10.2_10.2.36+maria~stretch_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/mysql: found previous version 10.1
Unpacking mariadb-server-10.2 (10.2.36+maria~stretch) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-server-10.2_10.2.36+maria~stretch_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mysql_install_db', which is also in package mariadb-server-core-10.1 10.1.47-0+deb9u1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-server-10.2_10.2.36+maria~stretch_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You upgraded mariadb-10.1 from the Debian Stretch repo with mariadb-10.2 from the mariadb.org repo. One Problem seems to be that the plesk packages want `virtual-mysql-server` installed which get pulled in by the mariadb-10.1 packages from the Debian Stretch repo but not by the ones from the mariadb.org repo. That already indicates that it might be a bad idea to upgrade.

The problem that halts the installation is that the file `/usr/bin/mysql_install_db` is part of the `mariadb-server-core` package in mariadb-10.1 but part of `mariadb-server` package in mariadb-10.2. Since `mariadb-server` package gets upgraded first, the file is still there and owned by another package.

The installation would most likely succeed if you'd remove the `mariadb-server-core-10.1` package (and therefore all its dependencies) before upgrading to mariadb-10.2. But this would still leave you with the plesk dependency problem.

Comment: Thanks, here they say that if installation fails  with unmet dependencies use apt --fix-broken install. I think they refer to virtual-mysql-server, Should I try? https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213403429--How-to-upgrade-MySQL-5-5-to-5-6-5-7-or-MariaDB-5-5-to-10-x-on-Linux-

Comment: apt-get remove mariadb-server-core-10.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: default-mysql-server
 psa : PreDepends: pp18.0.32-bootstrapper but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated br

Comment: This is one reason we do not support and try very hard not to answer questions about systems running Plesk or other web hosting panels. Such questions should be referred to vendor support.